# What does "some" refer to in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> And if there are shortcomings in the system of semi-direct democracy,
> Switzerland has neither suffered anarchy, as **some** have feared from the
> 19th century up to our days, nor has it experienced the political
> revolutions **others** had dreamed of.
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

I want to know what do **some** and **others** refer to in this context?

To some (and other) **countries** of some people?

Comment: As some people have feared. "Some can also mean some people" [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/some), and as other people have dreamed of others "Others pronoun 1. used to indicate that people or things are not the ones already mentioned"

Comment: **Some people** and **other people**.

Comment: some people and other people but not necessarily limited to the Swiss population...

Answer (score 1):

This statement divides public opinion in groups: ***some people*** feared that Switzerland has suffered anarchy, while ***other people*** dreamed of Switzerland experiencing political revolutions. I don't think these groups of people belong only to the Swiss nation.

Comment: Actually, it says that some people over the years **have been afraid** that Switzerland would suffer anarchy, not that they think it has!

Comment: Yes, it is true. Will edit. Thanks for pointing it out.